# All buttons of dinamically added matrix of ImageButtons became black

Tags: java, android

[image]

This is how it looked in the beginning. After I created new project and added this code with some modification, the view turn into smth like this(notice that only those buttons in the matrix are black):
[image]

Here is what my xml file contains:

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/main_container" >
    </LinearLayout> 

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_below="@id/main_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <Button 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/refresh_button"    
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/refresh"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/minesLeft"
        android:text="@string/minesLeft"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/refresh_button"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/minesLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/minesLeftCounter"/>

    </RelativeLayout>   



</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is how I created this:

```
map = new ArrayList<   ArrayList<ImageButton> >();
        LinearLayout mainContainer = (LinearLayout) c.findViewById(R.id.main_container);



                //Params used for cells
                TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        0, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f
                );
                int pixelsToDp = convertToPixelsDp(-4.5f);
                params.setMargins(pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp, pixelsToDp);

                //Params used for rows
                TableRow.LayoutParams rowParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                rowParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

                //Params used for table
                TableLayout.LayoutParams tableParams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                );
                tableParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

                //Table generation
                TableLayout table = new TableLayout(mAppContext);
                table.setLayoutParams(tableParams);
                table.setShowDividers(TableLayout.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
                table.setStretchAllColumns(true);

                for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
                    ArrayList<ImageButton> rowOfList = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();
                    TableRow row = new TableRow(mAppContext);

                    row.setShowDividers(TableRow.SHOW_DIVIDER_NONE);
                    row.setLayoutParams(rowParams);

                    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++){

                        ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(mAppContext);

                        btn.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
                        btn.setLayoutParams(params);
                        btn.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);



                        rowOfList.add(btn);


                        row.addView(btn);
                    }

                    map.add(rowOfList);
                    table.addView(row);
                }

                mainContainer.addView(table);
```

What could cause change the background color of ImageButtons? THank you!

Comment: 1) your changes 2) the default theme. Just compare the sources! (I use `meld` for that purpose on Linux, probably you would prefer something called like WindDiff)

Comment: @18446744073709551615 I guess the default theme would affect both that grey Button at the second picture as well, or would not?